# How to return a string that matches given strings in a variable

Tags: r, rvest

I'm scraping IMDb and want to categorize the movies by only one genre but they are returning multiple.

How do I make it so that they only return a genre that I specify?

```
IMBD_Movies <- html_session("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top")

movieTitles <- IMBD_Movies %>% 
html_nodes(".titleColumn a")%>%
html_text()%>%head(5)

genres <- c("Adventure", "Action", "Comedy", "Drama", "Horror")

IMBD_genres <- list()

for(i in movieTitles){
  genrePage <- IMBD_Movies %>% follow_link(i)
  IMBD_genres[[i]]$genre <- genrePage%>%
    html_nodes(".subtext .itemprop") %>% html_text()
}
```

Shawshank Redemption returns "crime" and "drama" but I only want "drama" to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am presuming you want only those genres to be output, that are mentioned in the genres vector that you have declared.

Adding the last line to your for loop gives me the results :

```
for(i in movieTitles){
  genrePage <- IMBD_Movies %>% 
               follow_link(i)
  IMBD_genres[[i]]$genre <- genrePage %>%
                            html_nodes(".subtext .itemprop") %>%
                            html_text()
  IMBD_genres[[i]]$genre <- IMBD_genres[[i]]$genre[which(IMBD_genres[[i]]$genre 
                            %in% genres)]
  }
```

The "which" gives you the required indices in your IMBD_genres[[i]]$genre.

Hope that helps.

Comment: that was it! Thanks!